# How to execute a query in PHP through a textbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I want to execute a query through a textbox area in HTML using PHP. I know this is prone to SQL injection but I'm not worried about that. Below is part of my current code..

SQL Output:

```
<?php

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

$query = "SELECT * FROM members"; // **I want to pass the query from a textbox value **

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    echo $row['username'] . $row['password']; 

}

?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can I pass the query from HTML textbox into the php code

Comment: <textarea id="message" name="SQL" placeholder="Input SQL"></textarea>



<?php
$sql = $_GET["message"];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
//show output
}else{
//error}
?>

Comment: From php --> $query = $_REQUEST['message'];

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to condone allowing SQL Injections all willy-nilly.
This is how you'd pass a value from a text field through to a php script, allowing you to use it in a query.

You need to set up your form.

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="the-field">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your php script (`process.php`), you'd have something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $field = $_POST['the-field']; // obviously you'd sanitize it here.

    // run the query using PDO/Mysqli, etc...
}
```

I **HIGHLY** encourage the use of [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the depreciated `mysql_*` functions.

here are some examples that you could follow:

- [PDO Tutorial for Mysql Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
- [Writing MySQL/PDO with PHP](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html)
- [Why you should be using PDO....](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

---

Here's an example of a PDO Query.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? AND name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($id, $name));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

<sup>([*Source*](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You have named the text box `SQL` and not `message`.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET["SQL"]) ) {
  $sql = $_GET["SQL"];
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if($result) { 
    //show output 
  } else {
    //error
  }
}
?>
```

As you have already pointed out, this is prone to SQL injection and is highly discouraged.

Comment: I am receiving the output Resource id #4

Comment: What are you trying to `echo`? You are probably trying to echo the MySQL handle or the resultset (such as the `$result` variable) variable before actually fetching the rows with something like `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: If I wanted to go out applying this to muiltple databases - so I don't have to specify the $row for example 


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";  


what would you suggest the best way of going about this?

Comment: Do you mean multiple tables? So you are wanting to pass in a query and display the entire result set?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this -- $query = "SELECT * FROM members";

With this --- $query = $_REQUEST['SQL'];